# Webdriver Python disable browser push notifications in Safari

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, safaridriver

I'm using Python to run Selenium WebDriver and am trying to disable browser push notifications in Safari.  I have been able to do this in my set up for Chrome and Firefox.

In Firefox I use the following code to disable push notifications:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
```

And in Chrome, I use this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
```

In Safari, I have tried, unsuccessfully, to disable push notifications using set_permission.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.set_permission("--disable-notifications", True)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @RodrigoGomez-Palacio, No I haven't.